# Is EF FirstOrDefaultAsync a true async or Task.Run wrapper?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, asynchronous, async-await

I'm having a hard time deciding whether my WCF Service should be async or not (I don't mean the client `Task.Run` wrapper, I mean the server contracts). From what I read the service should be async if it's calling a truly async functions, otherwise it's considered an anti-pattern (an actually hurts performance).

For example, I consider this an anti-pattern:

```
public async Task<ItemDto> GetItemDetails(int id)
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        using (var test = ContextFactory.CreateTestContext())
        {
            return test.TableA.AsNoTracking()
                      .Include(i => i.TableB)
                      .Include(i => i.TableC)
                      .Where(i => i.Id == id)
                      .Select(row => new ItemDto()
                      {
                          Id = row.id,

                      })
                      .FirstOrDefault();
        }
    });    
}
```

Imho it doesn't make sense, because it can be done on the client side. In this case you don't waste the main thread for waiting till DB returns, but you acquire another thread to do so.

So.. the only scenario, when the method `GetItemDetails` as async makes sense is when `FirstOrDefault` is truly async and I don't have to do `Task.Run` wrapper. Am I'm correct?

If so, the question is: Is **FirstOrDefaultAsync** a truly async function? If not, is there any truly async function to fetch data from DB (SQL Server) via EF?

I'm using EF6.

Thank you

Comment: EF6 is open source. Feel free to check out.

Comment: => https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/master/src/EntityFramework/QueryableExtensions.cs

Comment: @CodeNotFound I'm not sure. I can't see any Task.Run part. There is `ExecuteAsync`. The code is a little bit too complicated to me:/

Comment: @CodeNotFound Nope, try this one https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6

Comment: I found tracing back through all the source code is pretty hard. But EF sits on top of ADO.NET and that has had async I/O (using APM) from the beginning. And async/await adapts  to APM easily.